# Selecting an item in a TCD

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

With Excel VBA, I would like to select item 13/04/2020 in my TCD.
I try this code :

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems("13/04/2020").Select
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").PivotSelect "Date[" & "13/04/2020" & "]", xlDataAndLabel
```

But finally, the item 13/04/2020 isn't selected. Could you, please, help me ?

[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems("13/04/2020").LabelRange.Select`

Comment: @FaneDuru. Nothing changes.I also tried 4/13/2020 instead of 13/04/2020 but nothing helps

Comment: My above comment assumes that "13/04/2020" is a label of the field "Date". I make the assumption only seeing part of "4/15/2...". Can you put a relevant picture showing what "13/04/2020" is in fact?

Comment: @faneduru I just tried to select the item "04/14/2020" with this code ActiveSheet.PivotTables (1) .PivotFields ("Date"). PivotItems ("04/14/2020"). Visible = False
but nothing also passes

Comment: I told you: If I could not see your pivot table I cannot know what "04/14/2020" is! It can be a label of a (which) field (in which Data range), or whatever...

Comment: @FaneDuru, as the photo in my post shows, 14/04/2020 is in the same field "Date" as 13/04/2020. I don't understand What would you like as additional information

Comment: But to which data range does it belong? Can you please put a picture with your PIVOT TABLE? If it is in a data range you cannot select it only by its name, I am afraid. But it can be selected localizing in a different way (I hope)... Your picture is irelevant (at least, less relevant) for the purpose of the question. Or, not relevant for me...

Comment: @faneduru, I have added a new picture. the date 13/04/2020 is in "A" column

Comment: @faneDuru I changed the value of the option "Number of items to remember per field" to Automatic. And it works

Comment: Glad to hear that it works! Does it work using your original code?

Comment: @faneduru A simple refresh of the pivot table is enough to automatically check the item 04/13/2020.

Comment: @faneduru In fact it doesn't work when I change the source of pivot table

Comment: If you change the source, the appearance of your pivot table may cange. That's why I almost begged you to insert a picture **of the pivot table as you can see it on your sheet**. But, you inserted another irelevant picture with the pivot source, like I can imagine what is in that specific range... A pivot table is split in 'TableRange1', 'TableRange2', 'RowRange', 'ColumnRange', 'DataLabelRange', 'DataBodyRange', 'PageRange', 'PivotFields', 'PivotItems' and so on. Without seeing those elements I am afraid I cannot help you. Maybe somebody else is able to do that...

Comment: @faneduru if i understand correctly, you want a picture of the table where the pivot table is generated?

Comment: **Yes**. Otherwise, I cannot understand which elements must I take in consideration to think of a working code. If your cell to be processed will be, in a way, highlighted it will be even better. I can stay in my office for no more then half an hour...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208929/discussion-between-christophe-c-and-faneduru).

Comment: I will live my office now... Let me find some relevant links able to help you. Please look [here](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=154:referencing-an-excel-pivot-table-range-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475). It is very well explained (with visual examples) the way you must use VBA in order to solve your problem... I think is impossible to not solve the problem. If you don't, I will be at home in about three to four hours and I will try helping you. Now, your last picture is pointing to your pivot table? If yes, try looking to the link to see the way